# Cypress Cucumber error with cucumber-json-formatter

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

```
An error was thrown in your plugins file while executing the handler for the after:run event.

The error we received was:

Error: spawn resources/json-formatter/windows/cucumber-json-formatter ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter) guide. And added the file manually. But still have the same error. I'm using windows machine.

This is my preprocessorsrc.json

```
{
  "html": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/reports/test-results.html"
  },
  "json": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/reports/test-results.json",
    "formatter": "./resources/json-formatter/windows/cucumber-json-formatter"
  },
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "[filepath]/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "[filepath].{js,ts}",
    "cypress/e2e/api/step-definitions/*.{js,ts}",
    "cypress/e2e/ui/step-definitions/*.{js,ts}"
  ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO4MZ.png)

Comment: Try to delete a dot before "./resources/json-formatter/windows/cucumber-json-formatter"